# Smarty: Populate html table columns with smarty array variable

Tags: php, html, arrays, smarty

I'm having the following PHP code:

```
$Query1 = "Select ReportId,MailingFrequency from reports_scheduler WHERE UserId='$UserId'";
    $result1 = db::sql($Query1);
    $X = array();
    while($x = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        $this->smarty->assign("X",$x['ReportId']);// This gives '1'
        $this->smarty->assign("X",$x['MailingFrequency']);//This gives 'Saturday'
    }
```

My HTML code:

```html
{html_table loop=$X}
      <table id="resulttable" border="1">
      <tr> 
          <td>$X[0]</td>
          <td>$X[1]</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

When I run my code, instead of displaying values '1' and 'Saturday', only 'Saturday' is displayed. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite smarty `$X` variable, not creating an array. On 6th line you set `$X` to 1, on 7th line you set `$X` to `'Saturday'`. The previous value is overwritten.

First create new array, then put that into Smarty template.

```
$X = array();

while($x = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $X[0] = $x['ReportId'];
    $X[1] = $x['MailingFrequency'];

    $this->smarty->assign("X", $X);
}
```

When you have only 1 rows from DB, you don't need to use `while` loop, access directly to result, eg:

```
$x = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1); // instead of line with while()
```